# Ansible: how to display the name of the currently running included_tasks playbook file?

Tags: ansible

I wrote an Ansible role which does lots of things, it's called "common" and all Ansible hosts are using it.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
./common
│   ├── ./common/README.md
│   ├── ./common/defaults
│   │   └── ./common/defaults/main.yml
│   ├── ./common/handlers
│   │   └── ./common/handlers/main.yml
│   ├── ./common/meta
│   │   └── ./common/meta/main.yml
│   ├── ./common/tasks
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/base_packages.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/iptables.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/locale.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/main.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/pip.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/pip_packages.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/python.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/python2_centos6.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/python3_centos6.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/repo.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/selinux.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/time.yml
│   │   ├── ./common/tasks/vim.yml
│   │   └── ./common/tasks/yum.yml
│   ├── ./common/templates
│   │   ├── ./common/templates/chrony.conf.j2
│   │   └── ./common/templates/ntp.conf.j2
│   ├── ./common/tests
│   │   ├── ./common/tests/inventory
│   │   └── ./common/tests/test.yml
│   └── ./common/vars
│       └── ./common/vars/main.yml
```

main.yml looks like so:

```
---
# tasks file for common
- name: python installation on centos 6 machines
  block:
  - import_tasks: python2_centos6.yml
  - import_tasks: python3_centos6.yml
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "6"
- import_tasks: python.yml
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"
- import_tasks: pip.yml
- import_tasks: pip_packages.yml
- import_tasks: repo.yml
- import_tasks: yum.yml
- import_tasks: selinux.yml
- import_tasks: base_packages.yml
- import_tasks: iptables.yml
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "7"
#- import_tasks: time.yml
- import_tasks: locale.yml
- import_tasks: vim.yml
```

The playbook that I'm currently running:

```
---

# local_slave_playbook_c6.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_user_shell: /bin/bash
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - common
    - consul-client
    - hosts
    #- node-exporter
    - cron
    - jenkins-slave
```

While I run the "common" role on a server, I want to know which imported_tasks file is currently running for debug matters. So for example, while Ansible "takes care" for the installation of base packages, I want to add "base_packages.yml" to the title of the task.

I looked through the [list of Ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) but couldn't find the variable that I need.

There is one special variable that looks right "{{ ansible_play_name }}" but that gives me "localhost".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "add base_packages.yml to the title of the task" you'll have to add it to the names of the tasks. For example

```yaml
shell> cat base_packages.yml
---
- name: "base_packages: .... "
```

`sed` might help to automate it.